# multiple authintication in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three types of users admin, customer and vendor.

I want to make multiple authentication with the steps 
1- all user will be inserted in User Table and i will differentiate between them with `job_type`  field

1 => admin 2 => custeomer 3 => vendor

My question is how to  configure  `$gurde` in `user.php` (model) because i have multiple user types?

If I use default multiple authentication:
I make`$gurde` for admin table in admin model  or `$gurde`of customer service in customer model I will repeat data like email and password  and if I make a view for the front end I will make admin and vendor create a new user again.

```
user table :email|password
admin table  :email|password
```

I want  make all user register data like email and password in user tabel only.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to authenticate a user based on their user role and you don't want separate models for admin, vendor and customer?

Comment: yes how can i do that @RMcLeod

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of achieving this. Using gates and/or policies is probably the best way forward.

Gates are easy to setup they are defined in your `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` class.

```
Gate::define('edit-settings', function ($user) {
    return $user->job_type === 1;
});
```

Then where you want to do a check you can call your gate to check the user has permission.

```
if (Gate::allows('edit-settings')) {
    ...
}
```

Note that the user is automatically passed to the gate and you don't have to pass it yourself.

Gates are good if you only have a few places that you need them and for none CRUD actions, however if you need them for all CRUD actions then you are better off with policies.

Policies define all of the authorization for a particular model in one place. Laravel can create these for you `php artisan make:policy PostPolicy --model=Product` and then you put your authorization logic in each of the method stubs this produces.

Policies can be checked in a couple of ways, either as middleware on a route or called directly on the user you are trying to authenticate.

```
if ($user->can('update', Product::class)) {
    ...
}
```

Often you'll find a mixture of Guards and Policies are required.

Take a look at the [Authorization Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization) on the Laravel site, it is very thorough and has examples.